# How to render complete page when overriding page--node--add--typename.tpl.php

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I'm trying to add more buttons to a custom content type form. 
I create a page--node--add--typename.tpl.php where I modify the form then render it:

```
$form = node_add('answer');

$form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
    '#type'   => 'submit',
    '#value'  => t('Cancel'),
    '#access' => TRUE,
    '#weight' => 55,
    '#submit' => array('cancel_button_form_cancel', 'node_form_submit_build_node'),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
);

print drupal_render($form);
```

However this only renders the form. Menus and other blocks are not rendered.

THanks.

Comment: The code is in the template file or `hook_form_alter`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you  would need to return the form, not print it.

```
return drupal_render($form);
```

Printing from a function will cease the theme engine which would cause the other parts of the page not rendered.